# Custom core-drawer-panel toggle attribute not opening hidden drawer

Tags: android, jquery, attributes, toggle, polymer

I would like to ask help with `core-drawer-panel` `toggleAttribute`.
I am in course of building a web app using Polymer, and I need to use at least two `core-drawer-panel` elements. This means that I need to modify the toggle trigger of the drawers, but if I perform this modification as shown below in this code snippet it is not working:

```
<core-drawer-panel toggleAttribute="custom-drawer-toggle">
    <core-header-panel drawer>
        <core-toolbar>
            <div>Application</div>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div> Drawer content... </div>
    </core-header-panel>
    <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar>
            <core-icon-button icon="menu" custom-drawer-toggle></core-icon-button>
            <div>Title</div>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div> Main content... </div>
    </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much!
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge the `core-drawer-panel` does not have a `toggleAttribute`, each drawer specifically looks for a child with a `core-drawer-toggle` attribute and adds listeners to it.

If you're running into issues you could manually setup your listeners like so:

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawer1" responsiveWidth="700px">
  <core-header-panel drawer>
    <core-toolbar>
      Menu
    </core-toolbar>
  </core-header-panel>
  <core-header-panel main>
    <core-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button on-tap="{{toggleDrawer}}" icon="menu">
      </paper-icon-button>
      <div>Main</div>
    </core-toolbar>
  </core-header-panel>
  <core-toolbar main>
    Footer
  </core-toolbar>
</core-drawer-panel>

// in your element definition

Polymer({
  toggleDrawer: function() {
    this.$.drawer1.togglePanel();
  }
})
```

This would let you create separate methods if you want "togglePrimaryDrawer" and "toggleSecondaryDrawer" for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It seams that I was mistaken, I thought that as I can specify the `responsiveWidth` I can do the same with the toggle. I just solved the issue by creating a new element extending the `core-drawer-panel` and now everything works like a charm :)